# Using a C# DLL confused with ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, obfuscation, confuserex

In my application project in Visual stuido, I am trying to reference a DLL confused with ConfuserEx (from another project). Even if I use the "none" preset, at runtime, when the DLL is loaded, my application crashes with the following message:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x063b523c, on thread 0x341c. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.'

[See a screenshot of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWK87.png)

The following is the project I use to process my DLL:

```
<project baseDir="path_to_input_dll_folder" outputDir="path_to_output_dll_folder" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
    <rule preset="none" pattern="true"></rule>
    <module path="path_of_dll_to_confuse" />
</project>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does it do the same if you build for Release? Was it obfuscated with the anti-debug option?

Comment: First action of business would be to run `peverify` on the output. It's not uncommon for these tools to contain bugs that cause them to output invalid code that the runtime can choke on in various creative ways.

Comment: I noticed that if I run my application by double clicking on the exe file, it works fine. Probably, even if I am not using any preset and I'm not using the anti-debug option, Confuserex prevents my application from being debugged somehow.

Comment: Can't you just obfuscate the DLL after the compilation and debug without obfuscation ? 
Do you have access to the no-obfuscate DLL ?

Comment: Clearly this obfuscator is worth what you paid for it.  You'll have to stop using it and file a bug report with the project so they can get it fixed.  This does require a repro project, rather the opposite of what the tool was made to do.  Hehe.  Do consider a commercial one that can provide you with the support you need.

Comment: @Cesar, yes I have access to the non-obfuscated DLL. In fact, I will keep developing with the non-obfuscated DLL and deploy with the obfuscated version. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One reason might be that `anti-debug` protection is added. You can add the following into your `crproj` file to disable that:

```
<module path="path_of_dll_to_confuse">
  <rule pattern="true" inherit="false">
    <protection id="anti debug" action="remove" />
  </rule>
</module>
```

Comment: This helped but what exactly it does?